# Find expected number

Tags: probability, means

Three students take a test with 50% of passing. Suppose that the test is opened every month. If a student fails, he will take the next test until he passes. Calculate the expected number of months that all of three students pass the test.

At the first sight, I thought this question is simple that I call X is the number of months that all of three students pass the test.
Then E(X) = $\Sigma_{x=1}^\infty x*f(x)$.However, it is very exhausted to calculate $f(x)$.

I also try to calculate separate probability on each student and use joint probability to calculate E(X) but I got stucked too.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Clarification requested: "Calculate the expected number of months that all of three students pass the test." : It seems that you are **not** requiring that all three students **pass the same test**.  Instead, it seems that you are merely requiring that a point is reached, where for each of three students, each student has passed either the current test, or some previous test.  ...question continued on next comment

Comment: For example, if student-1 passes the test in the first month, and therefore stops taking the test, and student-2 and student-3 both fail the first test and then both pass the test in the second month, this will count as all three students having passed, by the end of the 2nd test.  Is this interpretation what you intend by the question?

Comment: Hint: Re my previous comments (i.e. request for clarification) : If you intend the second interpretation, then I advise using recursion to attack the problem.  For $~k \in \{1,2,3\},~$ I would let $~E(k)~$ denote the expected number of **additional** tests needed, from this point forward, under the assumption that $~k~$ of the students have not yet passed (i.e. $~3-k~$ students have already passed).  Then, I would compute $~E(1).~$  Then, I would compute $~E(2),~$ based on the computed value of $~E(1).~$  Then, I would compute $~E(3),~$ based on the computed values of $~E(1)~$ and $~E(2).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability, $Q(j)$, that exactly $j$ months are needed for the students to all pass is the probability that every student takes at most $j$ months minus the probability that every student takes at most $j-1$ months.

Since the students’ results are independent we can write this as:

$Q(j) = P(j)^3 - P(j-1)^3$

where $P(j)$ is the probability that a student passes on attempt $j$ or before.

$P(j) = 1 - 1/2^j$

Substituting and simplifying, we get

$Q(j) = 3/2^j - 9/4^j + 7/8^j$

As a check, we can sum $Q(j)$ to infinity. Summing the three geometric series separately, we get the value $3-3+1 = 1$, which is correct.

But we want the *expectation*, i.e. the sum of $j*Q(j)$ to infinity.

This turns out to be $6-4+8/7 = 22/7$ which is a plausible value and I guess is unconnected with $\pi$ here!

Comment: Slightly shorter: the probability that $j$ months are not enough is $1-(1-\frac 1 {2^j})^3 = \frac 3{2^j}-\frac 3 {4^j}+\frac 1{8^j}$, and the expectation is the sum of this for $j=0,1,2,\cdots$. We only have to compute three easy geometric series.

I have made use of ${\rm E} X = \sum_{j=0}^\infty {\rm P}(X>j)$.

Comment: Yes that’s a useful trick to remember, and reaches the same value, confirming both our arithmetics. Thank you